# Cupom fiscal está cortando pela medate - Report builder

Tags: delphi, report-builder

Estou com problemas para imprimir um impresso de *Cupom não fiscal* pelo Report Builder, não está imprimindo todos os itens do pedido, eu estou inserindo *52* produtos e esta cortando no produto de sequência *36*.

Código:

```
dmRelatorios.cdsOrc.Active := False;
dmRelatorios.cdsOrc.Params.ParamByName('ECF_NUMERO').AsInteger :=  dmOperacao.cdsOrcECF_NUMERO.asInteger;
dmRelatorios.cdsOrc.Active := True;

dmRelatorios.cdsitOrc.Active := False;
dmRelatorios.cdsitOrc.Params.ParamByName('ECF_NUMERO').AsInteger :=  dmOperacao.cdsOrcECF_NUMERO.asInteger;
dmRelatorios.cdsitOrc.Active := True;


dmRelatorios.rptOrc.Template.FileName := strTemplateORCVENDA;
dmRelatorios.rptOrc.Template.LoadFromFile;
dmRelatorios.rptOrc.PrinterSetup.Copies := 1; 

    if strEscolheImpressoraORCVENDA = 'SIM' then
      dmRelatorios.rptOrc.ShowPrintDialog := True
    else
      dmRelatorios.rptOrc.ShowPrintDialog := False;

    if strTelaImpressoraORCVENDA = 'SIM' then
      dmRelatorios.rptOrc.DeviceType := 'Screen'
    else
      dmRelatorios.rptOrc.DeviceType := 'Printer';

    dmRelatorios.rptOrc.PrinterSetup.PrinterName := strImpressoraORCVENDA;

    for i := 1 to StrToInt(strNUMCOPIAORCVENDA) do
    begin
      dmRelatorios.rptOrc.Print;
    end;
```

Para imprimir os itens do pedido estou utilizando um `subReport`.
O problema é que não está imprimindo todos os itens do `subReport`.

Comment: Poderia deixar mais clara sua pergunta colocando informações de como está montando ele... estrutura em fim... acho que ajudaria.

Comment: Explique um pouco melhor o problema que está enfrentando e se possível coloque um pouco do seu código.

Comment: Qual o valor da variável `strNUMCOPIAORCVENDA`?

Comment: é strNUMCOPIAORCVENDA = 1

Comment: Então não tem muita lógica em usa-lo em um loop, `for i := 1 to StrToInt(strNUMCOPIAORCVENDA)...`. Já tentou mudar o `DeviceType`?

Comment: então só está usando esse loop caso o usuário queira imprimir mais de uma copia.
Estou usando o DeviceType = 'Printer', porque eu to imprimindo o cupom na impressora bematech MP-4200 TH.